# Can someone help me figure out how to put normal links into this Jquery Menu?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, hyperlink

So I have found this really nice jQuery menu on codrops

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/18/little-boxes-menu-with-jquery/

I have figured out most of it for myself how to modify. Most of it made sense, but I realised when I wanted to put normal links into the "boxcontent" portion, I couldn't. The CSS has this -

```
.littleBoxes{
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
.littleBoxes > div{
    position:absolute;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid white;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #555;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px #555;
    background-position:center center;
    z-index:999;
}
.littleBoxes div a{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    display:block;
    line-height:90px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    background:#91EF4A url(../bgItem.png) repeat-x top left;
    outline:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #777;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #777;
}
.littleBoxes div.boxcontent{
    width:334px;
    height:246px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:16px;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 10px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #777;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px #777;
    opacity:0.8;
    display:none;
}
```

Any link I made would have a background to it and would follow the script commands instead of going to a website. I had a look at the comments and there were solutions to it, but each time I did them, the menu just stopped functioning.

It said to I had to add a class to each top link element inside the boxes. 
Then, all I had to do is add this class to the bind function inside the script, like:
    $(‘#littleBoxes a.myClass’).bind(‘click’,function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $currentBox = $this.parent();

I've spent the weekend racking my brain and I came across psuedo classes and thought I would put a specific class per link, but the main CSS overrides it with its features.

This is my first time positing a question on here and I am hoping someone could help me understand how to properly tackle this. I am rather burnt out trying to make normal hyperlinks that link to other websites. :P

Sorry for the newbish question.

thought I would add the general small portion of the site

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Little Boxes Menu with jQuery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Little Boxes Menu or Navigation with jQuery - 
radnomly animate the menu items to show content, accodion like boxes menu" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, boxes, menu, navigation, animate"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
        body{
            background:#E4FFCF url(on-music/wood.jpg) no-repeat top center;
            font-family:Futura, "Century Gothic", AppleGothic, sans-serif;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        h1{
            color:#fff;
            margin:40px 0px 20px 40px;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #555;
            font-weight:normal;
        }
        a.back{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:5px;
            right:5px;
        }
        .reference{
            position:absolute;
            bottom:5px;
            left:5px;
        }
        .reference p a, a.back{
            text-transform:uppercase;
            text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
            color:#666;
            text-decoration:none;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        .reference p a:hover, a.back:hover{
            color:#000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Little Boxes Menu with jQuery</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="reference">
            <p><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/adforce1/">Photos from 
williamcho's photostream on Flickr</a></p>
        </div>

        <a class="back" href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/18/little-boxes-menu-
with-jquery">Back to Codrops</a>
        <div id="littleBoxes" class="littleBoxes">
            <div class="boxlink bg1" style="top:0px;left:0px;">
                <a href="">About click me to see how far</a>
                <div class="boxcontent">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
                    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-90px 0;top:0px;left:95px;"></
div>
            <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-180px 
0;top:0px;left:190px;"></div>
            <div class="bg5" style="background-position:-270px 
0;top:0px;left:285px;"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /* object to save the initial positions of each box */
            var divinfo = {"initial": []};
            /* index of the selected / clicked box */
            var current = -1;

            /* we save the index,top and left of each one of the boxes */
            $('#littleBoxes > div').each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var initial = {
                            'index' : $this.index(),
                            'top'     : $this.css('top'),
                            'left'     : $this.css('left')
                };
                divinfo.initial.push(initial);
            });

            /* clcik event for the anchors inside of the boxes */
            $('#littleBoxes a').bind('click',function(e){
                    var $this         = $(this);
                    var $currentBox    = $this.parent();
                    /* set a z-index lower than all the other boxes,
                    to see the other boxes animation on the top*/
                    $currentBox.css('z-index','1');

                    /* if we are clicking on a expanded box : */
                    if(current == $currentBox.index()){
                        /* put it back (decrease width,height, and set the top and 
left like it was before).
                        the previous positions are saved in the divinfo obj*/
                        $currentBox.stop().animate({
                                'top'         : divinfo.initial[$currentBox.inde
()].top,
                                'left'        : divinfo.initial[$currentBox.inde
()].left,
                                'width'     : '90px',
                                'height'    : '90px'
                        },800,'easeOutBack').find('.boxcontent').fadeOut();


                        $('#littleBoxes > div').not($currentBox).each(function(){
                            var $ele         = $(this);
                            var elemTop     = divinfo.initial[$ele.index()].top;
                            var elemLeft     = divinfo.initial[$ele.index()].left;
                            $ele.stop().show().animate({
                                'top'         : elemTop,
                                'left'        : elemLeft,
                                'opacity'    : 1
                            },800);
                        });
                        current = -1;
                    }
                    /* if we are clicking on a small box : */
                    else{
                        /* randomly animate all the other boxes.
                        Math.floor(Math.random()*601) - 150 gives a random number
between -150 and 450.
                        This range is considering the initial lefts/tops of the
elements. It's not the exact right
                        range, since we would have to calculate the range based on
each one of the boxes. Anyway, it
                        fits our needs...
                        */
                        $('#littleBoxes > div').not($currentBox).each(function(){
                            var $ele = $(this);
                            $ele.stop().animate({
                                'top' : (Math.floor(Math.random()*601) - 150) +'px',
                                'left': (Math.floor(Math.random()*601) - 150) +'px',
                                'opacity':0
                            },800,function(){
                                $(this).hide();
                            });
                        });

                        /* expand the clicked one. Also, fadeIn the content(boxcontent)
                        if you want it to fill the space of the littleBoxes container,
                        then these are the right values */
                        var newwidth     = 379;
                        var newheight     = 379;
                        $currentBox.stop().animate({
                            'top'     : '0px',
                            'left'    : '0px',
                            'width' : newwidth +'px',
                            'height': newheight+'px'
                        },800,'easeOutBack',function(){
                            current = $currentBox.index();
                            $(this).find('.boxcontent').fadeIn();
                        });


                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function() {
   var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
   if(!a.test(this.href)) {
       $(this).click(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           event.stopPropagation();
           window.open(this.href, '_self');
       });
   }
});
```

This seems much smoother.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this bit

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This stops the browser from following the link.

if you remove it the links will work but you will probably force the browser to refresh and it won't animate. I've not been able to try this but you need to check if it's not an external link before you prevent it from working.

you'll need something like this instead

```
if(e.href != e.baseURI) { e.preventDefault(); }
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. I went ahead and tried it but the boxes, as you said, dont want to animate.

     current = $currentBox.index();
                               $(this).find('.boxcontent').fadeIn();
                            });
    }
                        if(e.href != e.baseURI){e.preventDefault();}
                });

Comment: I've tried contacting the owner but I havent heard anything yet. Its really weird. If i put in a normal hyperlink to a website, it gains a border due to the CSS. I figure I need to make a new class, but if I go to bind it, it stops animating. I must be writing something incorrectly in the CSS. I just wish I knew what. I tried so many different variations of "myClass" literally.

Answer (score 0):

OK! I have figured it out.

Change

```
$('#littleBoxes > div').each(function(){
```

to

```
 $('#littleBoxes > div','myClass').each(function(){
```

For targeting the DIV's CSS add this

```
 $('myClass').removeClass('#littleBoxes a').addClass('#myClass a');
```

The CSS was changed to

```
.myClass div a{
text-transform: none;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: normal;
letter-spacing: normal;
display: inline;
line-height: normal;
text-decoration: underline;
color:#000000;
background: none;
outline: none;
text-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

And it worked :D!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: location = 'http://www.google.com';" >Google</a>
```

That's worked :) Another codes not worked!